# Can't write to USB drives on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: usb-drive

I cannot write to any USB drives, hard drives or flash. They mount fine and I can read off them but can't copy anything to them as it tells me I do not have permission. My drives are formated from my mac as mac journald and the permissions are to let everyone read and write to them.

From Linux the permissions are `owner user#99`

How can I write to these devices?

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn off journaling if you want to be able to read/write to it from Ubuntu. Ubuntu only has support for writing to non-journaled HFS+ volumes.  Linux can read HFS+ volumes. It can also write to HFS+ volumes, but only if they're formatted without journaling.

On your Mac, you can do so from disk utility, or open terminal, and do:

```
diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/Macintosh HD
```

Then you can mount the partition on Ubuntu

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sdax /media/mac
```

<sup>Complements of Z.Hossain</sup>